# amcharts pie chart will not load data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amcharts

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetTaskStatus()
{
    TaskPieChart model = new TaskPieChart();
    return Content(model.getStatus(1), "application/json");
}
```

**Model:** *All the implementation details contains waaaaaaaaay too much code, but it DOES return a valid JSON string (model.getStatus will end up returning jsonResult) using the following method:*

```
public string DataTableToJSON(DataTable dt)
{
    string jsonResult = "";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("dataSet");
    dataSet.Namespace = "NetFrameWork";
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
    dataSet.AcceptChanges();

    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);

    return jsonResult;
}
```

**JSON file** returns data in this format

```
{
  "project.Tasks_Status": [
    {
      "TaskName": "Task 1",
      "TaskCompleted": 1000.0
    },
    {
      "TaskName": "Task 2",
      "TaskCompleted": 0.0
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**View**

```
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script>
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "pie",
    "theme": "light",
    "titleField": "TaskName",
    "valueField": "TaskCompleted",
    "dataLoader": {
        "url": "../Home/GetTaskStatus",
        "format": "json"
    },
  });
</script>
```

The problem is, once I load my view, VS throws an exception and highlights the above code (within my script tag) with the following error message:

> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 5209 in http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js
>   0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Is anyone familiar enough with amcharts to help me out? It would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any assistance you may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1) Since you're making a pie chart, you need to include `pie.js` in your view. `serial.js` is meant for lines and columns:

```
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
```

2) The dataLoader expects the return value to be the array objects, not an object that contains an array, i.e.:

```
[
    {
      "TaskName": "Task 1",
      "TaskCompleted": 1000.0
    },
    {
      "TaskName": "Task 2",
      "TaskCompleted": 0.0
    },
    ...
]
```

You either need to fix your payload to return just the array or use the dataloader's [`postProcess`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#complete-list-of-available-dataloader-settings) callback to specify the array in the `project.Tasks_Status` property from your payload:

```
"dataLoader": {
    "url": "../Home/GetTaskStatus",
    "format": "json",
    "postProcess": function(data) {
        return data["project.Tasks_Status"];
    }
}
```

Comment: "Genius. Pure genius." - Donatello (TMNT)